# Want to display git commits by respective authors on jira page

Tags: git, jira

We have one jira wiki page and i want to display the git commits by authors on the wiki page automatically. Is there any way to do so.

PS: I don't have admin privileges to jira.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not clear. What exactly is what you call a "jira wiki page" ? Jira is an issue tracking tool, the wiki part of the Atlassian suite being Confluence, so I wonder if you are using some plugin.

In any case, one of the smoothest way to interact automatically with Jira is its rest API :

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/